# GitHub GraphQL api says there's another page, but when using a cursor no results are found

Tags: graphql, github-api

I have a basic query to obtain information about some issues.

```
query getIssues($owner: String!, $repo: String!, $milestoneId: Int!, $cursor:String) {
  repository(owner: $owner, name: $repo) {
    milestone(number: $milestoneId) {
      title
      issues(first: 100, after:$cursor) {
        totalCount
        edges {
          node {
            title
            state
            createdAt
            closedAt
          }
        }
        pageInfo
        {
          hasNextPage
          endCursor
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I use the arguments :

```
{"owner": "Me", "repo": "MyRepo", "milestoneId": 1, "cursor": null}
```

I receive information about the first 100 issues. There's a `totalCount` of 213, the `paginationInfo` tells me that there's another page and gives me a cursor to go to the next page.

When I do another query with the field `$cursor` replaced to the value of the cursor that was given by `endCursor`. I receive this as an answer :

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "milestone": {
        "title": "MilestoneName",
        "issues": {
          "totalCount": 213,
          "edges": [],
          "pageInfo": {
            "hasNextPage": false,
            "endCursor": null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there an additional step to get pagination with cursor to work?